# Log format documentation

Tags: logs, nginx

I'm trying to create a log format for [goaccess](https://goaccess.io/man#configuration) so it can parse my nginx logs but it's failing and I can't find the documentation on what the the placeholders mean in the first place.

Where can I find the documentation for the placeholders; like **%^**, **%T** and **%d** and so on?

```
log-format %^ - [%^] - %^ - [%d:%t %^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" %T ~h{," }
```

Comment: Hi @TugboatCaptain. I believe it is in the same link that you had provided under `SPECIFIERS`. Otherwise, I might be misunderstood your question!